# Selenium test responsive navigation

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm writing a selenium test for our navigation, the application is of course responsive, and when its in Smartphone size I get the classic bootstrap navigation icon.

Now, when I click a link in responsive mode the navigation automatically close the menu, so for clicking the next link I need to open the menu again etc.

So I created a simple for loop so when the Responsive Menu is visible it click to open the menu first and later the link.

This works nice and quite fast, but since i repeat the Open Menu loop every time i clicked the link the code looks ugly. So my question is. Could this be nicer? or is this the lottery when trying to create one method for both desktop and smartphone?

Btw Im using PageObjects

This is what I have, and as you can the Open_Navigation repeat its self dozens of time

```
    public Open_Navigation()
    {
        if (lnkOpenNavigation.Displayed)
            lnkOpenNavigation.Click();
       return this;
    }

    public Homepage navigate_the_site()
    {
        Open_Navigation();
        lnkCreate.WaitForCondition(x => lnkCreate.Displayed, 5000);
        lnkCreate.Click();
        lnkContracts.Click();
        Open_Navigation();
        lnkLibraries.WaitForCondition(x => lnkLibraries.Displayed, 5000);
        lnkLibraries.Click();
        lnkClauseLibrary.Click();
        Open_Navigation();
        lnkReports.WaitForCondition(x => lnkReports.Displayed, 5000);
        lnkReports.Click();
        Open_Navigation();
        lnkAdministration.WaitForCondition(x => lnkAdministration.Displayed, 5000);
        lnkAdministration.Click();
        lnkAccount.Click();
        Open_Navigation();
        lnkAdministration.WaitForCondition(x => lnkAdministration.Displayed, 5000);
        lnkAdministration.Click();
        lnkUsers.Click();
        Open_Navigation();
        lnkAdministration.WaitForCondition(x => lnkAdministration.Displayed, 5000);
        lnkAdministration.Click();
        lnkMasterData.WaitForCondition(x => lnkMasterData.Displayed, 5000);
        lnkMasterData.Click();
        Open_Navigation();
        lnkSupport.WaitForCondition(x => lnkSupport.Displayed, 5000);
        lnkSupport.Click();
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not a

> lottery when trying to create one method for both desktop and smartphone

I'm not a big fan of PageObject, but since your solution relies on it, you can use [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), because at run time

> lets the algorithm vary independently from clients that use it

So your navigation is a sequence of steps (algorithm) and you can let it vary depending from the browser size (client). Simply put - determine the client in your `SetUp()` method and just call the appropriate `INavigationStrategy` for the particular case.